# Question about Google openid.claimed_id

Tags: perl, authentication, openid, google-openid

I am using openid authentication in my web application. 
I have two tables, one for storing multiple openid_url for any user_id and with openid as primary key.

There is another table with user details with user_id as primary key.

my authentication works and after that I check if the url returned is available in my openid table, if its not there, I redirect to a create user form, while if the url is there, user is redirected to page where he was.
But I am facing a strange issue where in the url returned for my email id after google authentication does not match with the value stored in db a day before or so.

I am not sure if I am missing something or do I have to use some thing else in openid 2.0.

Any clue at this point is highly appreciated.

### Edit:

I got one more thread which deals with information I am looking for.
[Why does the ID of Google's OpenID implementation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684618/why-does-the-id-of-googles-openid-implementation-change)

Comment: what modules are you using for openid authentication?  or if none, show your code?

Comment: I am using Catalyst::Authentication::Credential::OpenID module from cpan. I have referred [link](http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe).

Comment: Here is my catalyst app config for open id realm
`             openid => {
                ua_class => "LWPx::ParanoidAgent",
                ua_args => {
                   whitelisted_hosts => [qw/ 127.0.0.1 localhost /],
                },
                credential => {
                   class => "OpenID",
                },
               store => {
                  class => 'Null'
               },
             }
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google uses unique identifiers for every service provider (relaying party).

Please verify that your side using a consistent openid.realm. That is the protocol and domain name of your side. For example: https://stackauth.com

If you mix using of a "www." prefix or not using it or mixing http or https, Google will see you as distinct service providers and provide different ids for the same user.

Comment: The module being used isn't providing a way to configure the openid.realm; it's using `$c->uri_for($c->req->uri->path)`.

Comment: and is $c->req->uri->path consistent?

Comment: yeh path is consistent as for now there is only one login action.

Comment: The end of the path is ignored. It's only protocol and domain name that is used. So if your website is reachable at http://example.com and http://www.example.com or via http://example.com and https://example.com than that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone thorough a number of documents and I am going to use email as user identifier only in case of google. This is one attribute which is uniq for any site any domain.

Comment: Hotmail E-Mail addresses expire after 6 month of not being logged in. The twitter which exposed internal management documents was done that way: http://techcrunch.com/2009/07/19/the-anatomy-of-the-twitter-attack/

Comment: thanks nhnb, but I ment that I shall be using gmail only for google for not not for any other open id provider. what you say?

Comment: my google account has a third party email address associated. I don't have an gmail account, but I can use my google account for openid authentication.